# Thread creation time on windows xp

Tags: multithreading, windows-xp

Can any one help me in identifying the total time consumed while creating a thread and deleting a thread on windows xp, assuming the same configurations.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not test it for yourself? Load up your favorite IDE...create threads in batches and kill them when desired.

Whatever examples we give here probably won't match your needs anyways.